# Find and replace with on PDF file from command line

Tags: command-line, pdf, text-processing

I want to find specific text or word from PDF file and replace it with another text and make a new PDF file from command-line. I tried with `sed`, `find`, `awk` series on text files but I want to get on PDF file. Which command line utility will help me?

Comment: PDF are usually compressed so plain text tools will not work.

Answer (score 23):

Use `pdftk` to uncompress the file, then edit via `sed` and finally recompress it.

```
pdftk input.pdf output uncompressed.pdf uncompress
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' uncompressed.pdf
# uncompressed.pdf now has all the changes
pdftk uncompressed.pdf output changed.pdf compress
```

Of course any text in images cannot be changes like this.

Comment: @denny Instead of writing "Thank you" comments, please accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the grey round check button on its left. Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please note that you can take the little [tour] to learn more about how our site works.

Comment: Even uncompressed PDF does not produce text exactly as you see on the screen. I had to export from Acrobat Pro to Microsoft Word (Tool > Export), unzip the docx, then perform search & replace on document.xml directly.

Comment: the replaced word should be of the same length, otherwise it doesn't look good :)

Comment: this doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could look like this...

You can convert pdf files to pure text files by using a couple of tools from the **poppler-utils** package.

It can be installed via:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Convert pdf file to text file

```
pdftotext /home/USER/Desktop/test.pdf /home/USER/Desktop/test.txt
```

Now you're able to do the editing and replacing on your pdf file.

After that you can convert it back by using a package called **cups-pdf** OR **text2pdf**.

Might be not the perfect solution, but should do its work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will work for text-only pdfs. However, it will most likely ignore any formatting and ignore (thus remove) images.